# SwiftUI: Apply the same modifier to every Stack element

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to create a stack, for example a `VStack`, and then apply a view modifier to every view inside of this stack without applying it manually to every view element? Is there a way to create a custom view and then iterate over all elements? `List` or `Section` do the same... or is this SwiftUI internal magic?

Comment: That’s the way it should work out of the box. Can you provide an example where it doesn’t?

Comment: Actually I'm just playing around with it and try to figure out, how the view modifiers apply to which view. It's really like you said, but for example it's very hard to create a divider between the views...

Comment: ... or for example make a different background color for every second view

Comment: What you've asked in comments is opposite to what you did ask in question.

Comment: No it's not. I asked how I can iterate over all elements. Actually it may be possible, but I didn't find a generic way (look here: https://medium.com/@prenezisbell_13570/a-short-note-on-viewbuilder-content-and-a-custom-vstack-in-swiftui-3f4f78629572)